# float: right makes all elements in reverse

Tags: html, css, widget, html-lists

Recently took over a site from a new client. Trying to make two div's in the header. Left is the logo. Fine, no problem there. But the right div has two elements and they should both be on the right hand side of that div. Tried floating right and changing margins, padding, etc. Not much working. Big issue is the order should be social icons and then MailChimp widget and instead, it's in reverse. Here's what I'm currently using for my CSS for that area:

```
    #theme-logo {
     width: 50%;
     float: left;
     margin: 0;
 }
 #theme-header {
     min-height: 60px;
 }
 #theme-header .tabcontent ul li.widget {
     position: relative;
     float: right!important;
     padding: 0px 20px;
 }
 #theme-header .tabcontent {
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     top:0px;
     width: 50%;
 }
 #theme-header .tabcontent ul {
     float: left;
     list-style: outside none none;
     margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: Are you talking about list items?

Comment: can you add html also?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The original theme had absolute positioning on the MailChimp widget's div. Like this:

```
#mc_signup { position: absolute; right: 0px; width: 226px; }
```

So I just deleted that line from the theme's CSS and problem seems to have been solved.

Never fun to take over a theme from someone else.